# KnockoutJS: How to quickly turn observables back into values

Tags: arrays, knockout.js

I currently have a observable array of objects which inside of those have observable properties.

```
appViewModel.diceArray = ko.observableArray( [ {
        diceAmount: ko.observable(1),
        diceType: ko.observable(null),
        diceAddition: ko.observable(0),
        diceMultiplication: ko.observable(1)
    } ] );
```

I am now looking to save the data to a database, and so need my array of objects (without them being observable).  Is there a quicker method than looping through the array and manually creating objects?

Comment: What do you mean by "quicker"? Are you talking program execution speed or least amount of code to type?

Comment: Least amount of code to type.  I find it cumbersome to code what I am trying to do currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ko.toJS

From http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html

> ko.toJS — this clones your view model’s object graph, substituting for each observable the current value of that observable, so you get a plain copy that contains only your data and no Knockout-related artifacts

Comment: ko.toJS certainly fulfills my request of keeping it very simple code wise. I am going to use that approach.

Answer (score 0):

If the potatopeelings' answer is not what you want. You can use the ko.utilsArrayMap:

```
var dices = ko.utils.arrayMap(appViewModel.diceArray, function(dice) {
    return { diceAmount: dice.diceAmount(),
             diceType: dice.diceType(),
             diceAddition: dice.diceAddition(),
             diceMultiplication: dice.diceMultiplication()
           }
});

//do something with dices
```

Answer (score 0):

ko.toJS is also available as an [industrial strength mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) which *also* supports going the other way, which you are going to need.